# using Maps in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary

if i've a set of address (repeatable) for which there is hit or a miss in l1 or l2.
How do I find the number of hits/misses for that address in L1 and L2.

```
map<int, pair<int, int> myMap;
while(!EOF){
    bool hit = test_bar(address); # L1
    if(!hit)
     bool hit1= test_bar(address); #L2

    myMap.insert(address,make_pair(hit, hit1));
}
```

Would that be correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it well, the proposed solution will not work, because there is no way to count the number of hits nor misses. Maybe you should consider something among these lines: The `counters` struct keeps track of the l1/l2 number of misses and hits. The `c` map maps each address to its counter.

```
struct counters {
    int l1_hits, l1_misses, l2_hits, l2_misses;
};

map<int, counters> c;
while (!EOF) {
    auto it = c.find(adress);
    if (it == c.end()) it = c.insert(address, {0,0,0,0});
    bool hit1 = test_bar(address); # L1
    if (hit1) ++it->second.l1_hits;
    else {
         ++it->second.l1_misses;
         bool hit2 = test_bar(address); # L2
         if (hit2) ++it->second.l2_hits;
         else ++it->second.l2_misses;
    }
}
// print
for (auto it : c) {
    cout << it.first 
        << " " << it.second.l1_hits 
        << " " << it.second.l1_misses
        << " " << it.second.l2_hits
        << " " << it.second.l2_misses << endl;
}
```

Comment: How can you sum them up now? and print?

Comment: What do you wish? A listing of the number of hits and misses for each address?

Comment: you forgot to do that.. :)

Comment: What is {0,0,0,0} required for?

Comment: In order to initialize the four counters to zero for each new address.